# contar carácter de un string ingresado pot input

Tags: javascript, html

Buen día, tengo una cuestión que no entiendo, se trata de un ejercicio en el cual el usuario debe ingresar una frase y un carácter, el script debe contar cuántas veces se repite dicho carácter en la frase; lo realicé capturando los datos con prompt y funciona bien:

```
<script>

var str = prompt("Escribe una frase"), caracter = prompt("Escribe un caracter"), coincidencias = contar(str, caracter);

function contar(str, caracter){
  var indices = [];
  for (var i = 0; i < str.length; i ++){
    if(str[i].toLowerCase()=== caracter) indices.push(i);
  }
return indices.length;
}

window.alert(coincidencias);

</script>
```

Ahora bien, cuando trato de trabajarlo para que reciba los datos a través de input y me muestre el resultado en un párrafo, no funciona.
estoy tratando de aprender y agradeceré enormemente a cualquier persona que me pueda explicar la diferencia y el porqué; esto es lo que modifiqué:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="es"
 <form>
        <input type="text" id="frase" placeholder="ingrese una frase"><br><br>
        <input type="text" id="caract" placeholder="ingrese un caracter"><br><br>

        <button type="button" id="btn" onclick="contar()" >Submit</button>

        <p id="resultado"></p>

    </form>

<sript>
var str = document.getElementById("frase").value;
var caracter = document.getElementById("caract").value;
var coincidencias = contar();

function contar(str, caracter){
  var indices = [];
  for (var i = 0; i < str.length; i ++){
    if(str[i].toLowerCase()=== caracter) indices.push(i);
  }
return indices.length;
}

document.getElementsById("resultado").innerHTML = coincidencias;

</sript>
</body>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Cuando haces el llamado a la función contar en el evento `onclick` no estás pasando los mismos parámetros que definiste en la función. Tu función original espera como primer parámetro un `str` y un `caracter`, y dentro de la función utilizas los parámetros que jamas has pasado.

Lo otro es que en esta línea

```
var coincidencias = contar();
```

Justo después de la carga de la página estarías contando lo que tienes en tus inputs, por lo que al principio al no tener ningún valor siempre te daría 0 el valor de `coincidencias` (Suponiendo que definiste y llamaste correctamente tu función).

Lo más sencillo que puedes hacer es asignar de inmediato el cálculo de las repeticiones a tu ID `resultado` y leer mientras ejecutas la función los valores de los inputs donde tienes la cadena original y el caracter a analizar, `coincidencias` leerás su valor inicial y ese será el valor con el cual vas a operar siempre la función, o sea `string` vacío.

Con todas estas anotaciones te propongo una corrección a tus problemas, cualquier duda quedo atento.

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="es"
 <form>
        <input type="text" id="frase" placeholder="ingrese una frase"><br><br>
        <input type="text" id="caract" placeholder="ingrese un caracter"><br><br>

        <button type="button" id="btn" onclick="contar()" >Submit</button>

        <p id="resultado"></p>

    </form>

<script>
  
function contar(){
  var str = document.getElementById("frase").value;
  var caracter = document.getElementById("caract").value;
  var indices = [];
  
  for (var i = 0; i < str.length; i++){
    if(str[i].toLowerCase() === caracter) indices.push(i);
  }

  document.getElementById("resultado").innerHTML = indices.length;
}


</script>
</body>
```

Comment: Muchas gracias, me sirvió mucho tu explicación. saludos

Answer (score 2):

El principal problema es que al obtener el `value` de los inputs, estos están vacíos, los tendrías que mover dentro de la función.

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="es" <form>
<input type="text" id="frase" placeholder="ingrese una frase"><br><br>
<input type="text" id="caract" placeholder="ingrese un caracter"><br><br>
<button type="button" id="btn" onclick="contar()">Submit</button>
<p id="resultado"></p>
</form>
<script>
  function contar(str, caracter) {
    var str = document.getElementById("frase").value;
    var caracter = document.getElementById("caract").value;

    let r = new RegExp(caracter, "g");
    let match = str.match(r);
    let repeticiones = (match) ? match.length : 0;

    document.getElementById("resultado").innerHTML = repeticiones;
  }
</script>
</body>
```

De paso, podrías también usar `.match()` porque podrías encontrar las conincidencias de cualquier cadena, no solo un caracter.

Answer (score 1):

1. Estas llamando la funcion `contar` sin que el usuario pulse en el boton y ademas sin los parametros.
2. `str` y `caracter` al inicio estas vacios.
3. `str.length` de error porque `str` no esta definido.
4. Tu etiqueta `script` esta mal escrita o al menos en el fragmento de código que has publicado.
5. Es `getElementById` en vez de `getElementsById` porque el `id` es único en teoría.

Con un par de cambios tu código quedaría de la siguiente manera:

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="es"
 <form>
        <input type="text" id="frase" placeholder="ingrese una frase"><br/><br/>
        <input type="text" id="caract" placeholder="ingrese un caracter"><br/><br/>

        <button type="button" id="btn" onclick="contar()" >Submit</button>

        <p id="resultado"></p>

    </form>

<script>


function contar(){
 var str = document.getElementById("frase").value;
 var caracter = document.getElementById("caract").value;
  var indices = [i];

  for (var i = 0; i < str.length; i ++){
    if(str[i].toLowerCase()=== caracter) indices.push(i);
  }
document.getElementById("resultado").innerHTML =  indices.length -1 ;
}

</script>
  
  

</body>
```

Lo que haces es ejecutar la función `contar` solo cuando el usuario pulse el boton `Submit` y entonces empiezas a procesar los datos.

Te dejo también un ejemplo de como sería utilizando el método `forEach` aun que se puede hacer de muchas maneras

```js
function contar(){
  let total = 0;
  let str = "Esta es mi cadena de texto"
  let caracter = 'e'
 
  Array.from(str).forEach(function(char){
    if(char.toLowerCase() === caracter.toLowerCase()) {
      total +=1
    }
  })
  console.log(`Total caracteres de ${caracter}: ${total}`)
 
}

contar()
```

Answer (score 1):

Tienes 2 errores:

- Estás definiendo los valores fuera de la función lo que hace que estés pasando `0` como parámetros a la función `contar()`.
- Se te fue una `S` en `document.getElementById('resultado')`.

```js
//var coincidencias = contar();
function contar(str, caracter){

var str = document.getElementById("frase").value;
var caracter = document.getElementById("caract").value;

  var indices = [];
  
  //console.log(str);
  
  for (var i = 0; i < str.length; i ++){
    if(str[i].toLowerCase() === caracter) indices.push(i);
  }

document.getElementById("resultado").innerHTML = indices.length;

}
```

```html
<form>
        <input type="text" id="frase" placeholder="ingrese una frase"><br><br>
        <input type="text" id="caract" placeholder="ingrese un caracter"><br><br>

        <button type="button" id="btn" onclick="contar()" >Submit</button>

        <p id="resultado"></p>

    </form>
```

Answer (score 1):

Los errores en tu código son debidos a que no pones cada cosa en su contexto.

Si los cálculos deben ocurrir dentro de `contar()` entonces puedes tomar dentro de la función los valores actuales de cada `input` y modificar allí mismo el valor del input del resultado.

La práctica implementada aquí consiste en:

1. Crear fuera de la función referencias a los elementos. Esto evitará tener que estar llamando constantemente a `document.getElementById` sobre todo si vas a usar esos en diferentes funciones.
2. Usar esas referencias dentro de la función para obtener los valores y/o cambiar el contenido.

```js
var elFrase = document.getElementById("frase");
var elChar = document.getElementById("caract");
var elResult = document.getElementById("resultado");

function contar() {
  var str = elFrase.value;
  var caracter = elChar.value;
  var indices = [];
  for (var i = 0; i < str.length; i++) {
    if (str[i].toLowerCase() === caracter) indices.push(i);
  }
  elResult.innerHTML = indices.length;
}
```

```html
<form>
  <input type="text" id="frase" placeholder="ingrese una frase"><br><br>
  <input type="text" id="caract" placeholder="ingrese un caracter"><br><br>

  <button type="button" id="btn" onclick="contar()">Submit</button>

  <p id="resultado"></p>

</form>
```

Comment: Muchas gracias por tu explicación, se ve que eres un buen maestro. jeje, saludos

Answer (score 1):

Tienes muchos errores pero con este código lo resolveras por lo general todo fue palabras mal colocadas

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="es"
    <head>

    </head>
    <body>
 <form>
        <input type="text" id="frase" placeholder="ingrese una frase"><br><br>
        <input type="text" id="caract" placeholder="ingrese un caracter"><br><br>

        <button type="button" id="btn" onclick="contar()" >Submit</button>

        <p id="resultado"></p>

    </form>
 <script>
function contar() {
        var str = document.getElementById("frase").value;
        var caracter = document.getElementById("caract").value;

        var indices = [];
        for (var i = 0; i < str.length ; i++) {
            if (str[i].toLowerCase() === caracter) indices.push(i);
        }
        var coincidencias = indices.length.toString();

        document.getElementById("resultado").innerHTML = coincidencias;
    }
</script>



</body>
    </html>
```